# How does empty() separation works?

Tags: php

I have these `if statements` with `empty()` function with vars `$a, $b, $c`

```
if (empty($a . $b . $c)) {echo 'empty.dot';}

if (empty($a && $b && $c)) {echo 'empty';}


if (!empty($a . $b . $c)) {echo 'filled.dot';}

if (!empty($a && $b && $c)) {echo 'filled';}
```

I got a weird result testing them like the following:

```
case[1]:
$a = '1';
$b = '1';
$c = '1';
result:
fillted.dot, filled

case[2]:
$a = '1';
$b = '';
$c = '1';
result:
empty, fillted.dot

case[3]:
$a = '';
$b = '';
$c = '';
result:
empty.dot, empty
```

What i don't understand is

Why in `case[2]` i got both `empty($a && $b && $c)` and `!empty($a . $b . $c)` = **`TRUE`**

Comment: only `isset()` works with multiples, not `empty()`.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner But why does it bring valid result in `case[1], [3]`?

Comment: it depends on what the expression inside `empty` evaluates to. the dots concatanate to either '111', '11', or ''. Only the last one is considered empty. With logical `&&` they evaluate to true, false and false. When you add these lines `$d=$a && $b && $c;
var_dump($d);` and `$e=$a . $b . $c;
var_dump($e);` above the ifs you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`empty`](http://php.net/empty) does not care about stuffing expressions in it. To make the behaviour more obvious, don't do that either. Split up your expressions into what they actually do:

```
$and = $a && $b && $c;
$cat = $a . $b . $c;

var_dump( empty($and) );
var_dump( empty($cat) );
```

And it's rather clear why

1. `(1 && "" && 1)` is `FALSE`, and thus `empty(FALSE)` is `TRUE`
2. `!empty("11")` returns `TRUE`.

Answer (score 1):

The `empty` function (or function-like feature) doesn't see the different variables you've used. Like any function, it sees a single value which you have passed in.

So we need to look at the expressions first:

```
$a && $b && $c
```

This treats each variable as a boolean, and evaluates to `true` if all three values are true-ish, `false` if any of them are false-ish. In the test cases you've used, `'1'` will be treated as true, and `''` as false.

```
$a . $b . $c
```

This treats each variable as a string, and concatenates them together into a longer string.

To see the value that `empty` is testing, just replace with `var_dump`.