# Isset() function doesn't work properly

Tags: php

```
$x = 1;

if (isset($x)) {$a = 1;}
if (isset($y)) {$b = 2;}

if (!isset($a, $b)) {
    echo "Hello";
}

if (!isset($a) && !isset($b)) {
    echo "World";
}
```

In my code here `$x` is `set` but `$y` isn't `set`,

As i know that `isset($a, $b)` is same as `isset($a) && isset($b)` or am i getting something wrong? because it works like `OR` instead of `AND`

I'm supposed to get nothing but i keep getting `Hello`.

Comment: Explain please what output you expect and what you get.

Comment: @u_mulder wrote it now, I'm supposed not to get any value at all since one of two values exists, So i doubt using `!isset($a, $b)` is equal to `!isset($a) && !isset($b)`.

Comment: Read what you've written by yourself properly.

Comment: @AakashVerma It is really confusing me how `isset($a, $b)` is same as `isset($a) && isset($b)` but `!isset($a, $b)` isn't same as `!isset($a) && !isset($b)`, But i suppose i understood the logic of `!` wrong.

Comment: you asked the complete opposite earlier [How does empty() separation works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47846254/how-does-empty-separation-works)

Comment: I'm closing this as a repost.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner where is Fred -ii-?

Comment: @u_mulder Fred who?

Comment: That guy Fred -ii-

Comment: @Matheo there's nothing you can understand wrong. What !(isset($a,$b)) does is it evaluates the isset first, which comes out to be false as $b is not set, and then makes it false with a `!`. But !isset($a) && !isset($b), first evaluates !isset($a) which turns out to be false and so stops evaluating further and returns the output of the entire expression in brackets as `false` as in an AND expression, no matter if the subsequent expressions are true, the whole expression becomes false if the first one is false. It's some sort of an optimization. This is only for AND operator though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to a manual:

> If multiple parameters are supplied then isset() will return TRUE only if all of the parameters are set.

So, if `$b` is **not set**, `isset($a, $b)` is **false**, and `!isset($a, $b)` is **true**.

Comment: `only if all of the parameters are set.` I don't get it from this part, I have `$x` isset but `$y` isn't, So i only get `$a`, But in `!isset($a, $b)` it returns `TRUE` even tho `$a` isset, Then how `all` works here?

Comment: `isset($a, $b)` returns __FALSE__, adding `!` to `isset` makes false  -> __TRUE__.

Comment: So i better use `!isset($a) && !isset($b)` only if i'm going with `!`?

Comment: What do you want to test?

Comment: I want to check if the two variables together are't set, If one of them isset then it returns true.

Comment: If you want to know if they are __both__ set, then test `isset($a, $b)`. Why do you add `!`?

Comment: **both**  'not' set, Since i'm not gonna use anything if they're both set.

Comment: If you want to test if __both__ not set - test each variable separately.

Answer (score 0):

isset($a,$b) => returns false;   !false == true;